# Can't use my USB wireless adapter D-link (DWA-131) to work Backtrack5 R1 VMware

Tags: networking

I have a USB wireless adapter D-Link DWA-131.
I also have backtrack 5R1 on Vmware.
I installed the driver on the system, and here are some outputs:

```
root@bt:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 07d1:3303 D-Link System DWA-131 802.11n Wireless N Nano Adapter(rev.A1) [Realtek RTL8192SU]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
root@bt:~# iwconfig
lo no wireless extensions.

eth1 no wireless extensions.

eth2 no wireless extensions.

wlan0 unassociated Nickname:"rtl_wifi"
Mode:Auto Access Point: Not-Associated Sensitivity:0/0 
Retryff RTS thrff Fragment thrff
Encryption keyff
Power Managementff
Link Quality:0 Signal level:0 Noise level:0
Rx invalid nwid:0 Rx invalid crypt:0 Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:0 Invalid misc:0 Missed beacon:0
```

Please note that the chip of the adapter is RTL8192SU,
and it's installed successfully on the system.

The problem comes when I can't use the wireless adapter to scan available networks.

```
root@bt:~# airmon-ng start wlan0
Interface   Chipset  Driver
```

How can I get this adapter to work?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that it just isn't supported yet. Your card doesn't appear on the [Backtrack Wireless Drivers page](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Drivers) (list below) so you may need to follow the instructions on the [Wireless-Compatibility page](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/Compat-wireless).

**Tested and working cards**
We were able to test the following cards. Note that "passed" means "passed an aireplay -9" injection test. We will be expanding on this list as more feedback domes form the community. From our testing we found that most major chipsets were supported, as well as the most common cards.

- AWUS036H (rtl8187, r8187) - both mac80211 and IEEE drivers - passed
- AWUS036NH (Ralink RT2870/3070) - using the mac80211 rt2x00usb drivers - passed
- BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01) - using the mac80211 b43, works well - passed
- Rockland N3 - (Ralink RT2870/3070) - using the mac80211 rt2x00usb drivers -passed
- Edimax EW-7318USG USB - (Ralink RT2501/RT2573) - using the mac80211 rt2500usb/rt73usb drivers -passed
- ASUSTek Computer, Inc. RT2573 - using the mac80211 rt2500usb/rt73usb drivers -passed
- Linksys WUSB54GC ver 3 - using the mac80211 rt2800usb drivers -passed
- Ubiquiti SRC - using the mac80211 ath9k drivers-passed
- Internal Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG - using the mac80211 iwl3945 drivers-passed
- Dlink WNA-2330 PCMCIA - using the mac80211 ath5k drivers-passed
- Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01) - using the mac80211 ath9k drivers-passed
- Netgear wg111v2 - using the mac80211 rtl8187 drivers-passed
- ZyXEL AG-225H v2 - using the mac80211 zd1211 drivers - passed
- Intel 4956/5xxx - using the iwlagn drivers - passed

**Working, without injection**

- Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 03)
- Broadcom Corporation BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)

**NON working cards**

- D-Link DWL-122 - using the mac80211 prism2_usb drivers - fail
- Linksys WUSB600N v2 - using the mac80211 rt2800usb drivers - fail
- AWUS051NH - fail
- D-Link DWA-131 using the airmon-ng driver detection - Fail